# Golang: Query with JOIN using GO-PG package

Tags: sql, go, go-pg

I need help with go-pg package and refactoring my query.
I have 2 tables

Table definition for Student :

```
type Student {
   ID int `json:"id"`
   UserID int `json:"user_id"`
   FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
   LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}
```

Table definition for Teams :

```
type Teams {
   ID int `json:"id"`
   StudentID int `json:"strudent_id"`
   TeamName string `json:"team_name"`
   CreateDate time.Time `json:"create_date"`
}
```

I have the following method which i am sure i can improve. I don't know how, but every time make a call to the base with JOIN query is not the best solution I'm totally sure
So here is my method

```
type Student struct{
   ID int `json:"id"`
   UserID int `json:"user_id"`
   FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
   LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}

type Team struct {
   ID int `json:"id"`
   StudentID int `json:"strudent_id"`
   TeamName string `json:"team_name"`
   CreateDate time.Time `json:"create_date"`
}

type StudentInTeam struct {
   UserID int `json:"id"`
   InTeam bool `json:"in_team"`
}


func (p *storage) FindStudentsInTeam (ids []int, teamID int)(map[int]bool, error){
    studentsInTeam := make(map[int]bool, len(ids))
    for _, id := range ids {
       res, err := p.Model((*Team)(nil)).
            Where("create_date <= ?", time.Now().UTC()).
            Where("team_id = teamID").
            Join("JOIN students ON students.id = student_id").
            Where("students.user_id = ?", id).
            Exists()
       if err != nil {
            return nil, err
       }
       studentsInTeam[id] = res
    }
    
    return studentsInTeam, nil
}
```

Will be appreciate for any help or advise.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying inside a loop is not always a good idea. You can use `IN` clause to check the `ids` are exists in the table.

You can use `Column` method to select some specific columns

```
func (q *Query) Column(columns ...string) *Query {
    ..... 
}
```

You can rewrite your method as follows

```
func (p *storage) FindStudentsInTeam(ids []int, teamID int) (map[int]bool, error) {

    // rest of your codes

    var existedStudentTeams []Team
    err := p.Model(&existedStudentTeams).
        Column("team_id").
        Where("create_date <= ?", time.Now().UTC()).
        Where("team_id = ?", teamID).
        Join("JOIN students ON students.id = student_id").
        Where("students.user_id IN(?)", pg.In(ids)).
        Select()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    // rest of your codes
}
```

See More about

- [Defining models](https://pg.uptrace.dev/models/)
- [SQL placeholders](https://pg.uptrace.dev/placeholders/#sql-placeholders)
- [Writing queries](https://pg.uptrace.dev/queries/#writing-queries)

Answer (score 0):

try this
//

```
   func (p *storage) FindStudentsInTeam(ids []int, teamID int) (map[int]bool, error) {
    studentsInTeam := make(map[int]bool, len(ids))

    // Prepare the query
    query := p.Model((*Team)(nil)).
        Select("students.user_id").
        Where("create_date <= ?", time.Now().UTC()).
        Where("team_id = ?", teamID).
        Where("students.user_id IN (?)", ids)

    // Execute the query
    var result []StudentInTeam
    if err := query.Find(&result).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Build the result map
    for _, student := range result {
        studentsInTeam[student.UserID] = true
    }

    return studentsInTeam, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but my IDE give an eror after `Select("students.user_id").` after the dot suggest only `Error()`